# CSS rendering wrong on IE7 & IE 10 compatability

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I've created a [website](https://commissies.ch.tudelft.nl/wiewie/).

On all browsers, except for IE7 & IE10 compatibility it is rendering just fine.

On these specific browsers, there is weird whitespace below the page and finally the picture sliders.

I've tried targeting these browsers specifically using css hacks, however; all of these were unsuccessful.

Comment: do you mean that whitespace you get below your page?

Comment: Exactly, and I've got no clue why and how this is happening, as these boxes are rendered next to eachother exactly as I want it. Just at this weird position...

Comment: Gee, IE renders CSS wrong???

Comment: this really is weird. you could try giving your .container-narrow and/or your row-fluid a float. 
If would have to look at it closer later if that doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to render the same in Chrome & IE10 here, so no idea what the issue is...

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your input. This however did not fix the problem :(

Comment: first of all repair validation errors. specialy once with ul and div http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcommissies.ch.tudelft.nl%2Fwiewie%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 then check if ie is not rendering bad in ie10 because of compatibility mode switch on. If yes just get reed of it using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`. You will have only ie7 left. I cannot say more, because I am lucky guy without ie :)

Answer (score 0):

Can this fix your problem?

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #28A31E;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure what wrong behavior do you mean. In G chrome, I see large white space below page. In IE10 I don't see sliders at all and page is very long, but it seems that is ok because of right panel...